# Validate Certification X509 online from specific CA like Verisign programmatically

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate, x509certificate2, ca

I want to take the X509Certificate2 certification and access online CA and check if it's true or not ... I notice that code in C# do something like that but I don't know how it access online and which CA it access. The code is here:

```
X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
X509ChainPolicy chainPolicy = new X509ChainPolicy()
{
    RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online,
    RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain
};
chain.ChainPolicy = chainPolicy;
if (!chain.Build(x509))
{
    foreach (X509ChainElement chainElement in chain.ChainElements)
    {
        foreach (X509ChainStatus chainStatus in chainElement.ChainElementStatus)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(chainStatus.StatusInformation);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
else { return true; }
```

Comment: Could you be looking for someting like `chainElement.Certificate == verisignCert` in the foreach?

Comment: I mean i want to take the certificate from my Local store and check it online in Versign's Database itself and return if it valid or not ..... maybe a hacker put a wrong certificate in my store so i need a way for this validation

Comment: If a hacker can put something in your local machine store then he can also alter/bypass you validation mechanism.

Comment: Yes you are right but if we consider that the validation mechanism is protected

Comment: From my point of view if a hacker is already in control of your server then it is not your server anymore. There is no protection :)